# Zoom page with Codeception?

Tags: php, jquery, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

My problem is that I have to test a page with Codeception in a small screen, wich hide some elements from the page (the design is responsive), so Codeception does not detect them.

So I'm trying to zoom out with Codeception, and I already tried this:

```
$I->executeJS("$('body').css('zoom','90%');");
```

But only works partially, because the page doesn't recognize that zoom change (works if I use 'Ctrl+-').
Therefore, I have also tried:

```
$I->pressKey('body', array(WebDriverKeys::CONTROL, WebDriverKeys::SUBTRACT));
```

and

```
$I->executeInSelenium(
    function(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver){
        $webdriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName("body"))->sendKeys(WebDriverKeys::CONTROL, WebDriverKeys::SUBTRACT);
    }
);
```

And some variations of it, but nothing happens...

I also found this page: [Selenium Zoom-in/Zoom-out](http://seleniumworks.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/zoom-in-zoom-out-windows-mac.html)
but couldn't figure out how to use those codes with Codeception.

If there is a way to configure chromedriver to use a specific zoom level, that also will solve my problem, but a zoom function would be more useful.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this works fine for me:

```
$I->executeJS("$(body).setStyle({zoom: '90%'});");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That returned a `body is not defined` error. I also tried with `$('body')` and `$(document.body)`, but I got a `$(...).setStyle is not a function` error.

Answer (score -1):

This works for Firefox:

```
$I->executeJS("document.body.style.transform = 'scale(0.8)';");
```

(zoom out to 80% of the original content)

Comment: Scaling is not the same as zooming.